# Fitting 3 Point Exponential Equation with Inverse Power

Tags: graphing-functions, linear-regression

I am trying to calculate the parameters of the Vogel−Fulcher−Tamman Equation. $T$ is temperature and $a,b,c$ are constants to be found.

$$\eta = a\exp(\frac{b}{T-c})$$

The experimental values are below

| Temp /k | Viscosity $\eta$ |
| --- | --- |
| 293 | 313.9 |
| 313 | 75.6 |
| 373 | 7.6 |

I have tried the following:
$$\ln \eta = \ln a + \frac{b}{T-c}$$

If it was $\ln \eta = \ln a + \frac{b}{T}$, I could plot $\ln \eta$ against $\frac{1}{T}$ and the gradient would give b and the y-intercept would give me $\ln a$.

I don't know how to account for the $T-c$ in the denominator?

Comment: Which variable are you solving for?

Comment: @TymaGaidash I am solving for a, b and c. I am given $\eta$, viscosity, and T, temperature, which in reality would be measured experimentally at various temperatures with the viscosity of the fluid measured..

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a closed form solution.

You have three equations in three unknowns $x$, $y$ and $z$ of the form
$$
x - r_i = \frac{y}{s_i - z}
$$
for known values corresponding to $i = 1,2,3$.

If you subtract the first from the second and the third you have two equations
$$
r_1 - r_2 = y\left(\frac{1}{s_2-z} - \frac{1}{s_1-z} \right)
$$
$$
r_1 - r_3 = y\left(\frac{1}{s_3-z} - \frac{1}{s_1-z} \right) .
$$
Then the ratio of those two equations is a single ugly nonlinear equation in $z$.

Solve it numerically and work backwards to get $y$ and then $x$.